# C++ combining namespaces

Tags: c++

I have some shared files that I want to use between two programs A and B that have the same compile target and are very identical.

So, I tried to separate them into two namespaces and create a shared namespace for the shared files

Interfaces.h

```
namespace ns_s {
    class SomeClass;
    class IFoo {
        virtual void bar(SomeClass*) = 0;
    };
}
```

SomeHeaderinA.h

```
#include "Interfaces.h"

namespace ns_a {
using namespace ns_s;

    class Foo : public IFoo {
        virtual void bar(SomeClass* p) override { ... }
    };

}
```

However the compiler is complaining now that my member function bar does not override anything, so it seems to not see the interface implementation.
Why is that the case? And why does the compiler not already complain about a missing class IFoo?

EDIT:
Looks like I missed an essential part that contributes to the problem. I pre-declared a class that is a parameter of the interface method. Now that I ahve a pre-declaration in namespace shared and an actual declaration in namsepace A those things are not the same anymore.

Is there a good way to fix this? Only a small subset of interfaces have arguments that are defined in one or the other namesapce (A or B), so I could leave different implementations in each of them, but it would be nice to have it all in the shared space if possible in a clean fashion.

Here is a link
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79fa58e50e7b8637

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/567d40d34199af73

Comment: Actually if it complains only about overridden function then it must've found some IFoo declaration, just maybe not the one you wanted it to

Comment: Oh, thanks. So, I assume that means I fundamentally do the right thing but do it wrong somewhere. That helps to know

Comment: Please show all the relevant code to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Please check any code you post with a compiler to make sure it produces the problem you are reporting.

Comment: added link that replicates

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

As shown in the linked code, the problem is caused by `SomeClass`.

The line

```
class SomeClass{};
```

declares and defines `SomeClass` in namespace `ns_a`. It does not define `SomeClass` in namespace `ns_s`.

The declaration of class `ns_s::IFoo::bar` uses `ns_s::SomeClass`.

The declaration of class `ns_a::IFoo::bar` uses `ns_a::SomeClass`.

That's the override is an error.

**Solution**

You can fix it by:

1. Removing the definition of `SomeClass` from `ns_a`, or
2. Using `ns_s::SomeClass` in the declaration of ns_a::IFoo::bar.

---

```
namespace ns_a {

  using namespace ns_s;

  class Foo : public IFoo {
    virtual void bar(SomeClass* p) override {}
  };
}
```

or

```
namespace ns_a {

  using namespace ns_s;

  class SomeClass{};

  class Foo : public IFoo {
    virtual void bar(ns_s::SomeClass* p) override {}
  };
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Hence, may question is changed to how can I fix that;)